# window object acting strange in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript

Consider the following sample HTML:

```
<div id="about">
 <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

And the following script

```
var about = (function ($, window, document) {
    "use strict";

     var methods;

     methods = {
        init: function () {
        // Do things here 
        }
     };

     return methods;
} (jQuery, window, document));
```

The variable `about` should be attached to the `window` object at this point.

In Firefox (3.6.17) I am able to write

```
window["about"]
```

And if about hasn't been processed yet this will return `undefined` if it has it will return the object just as I expect.

However, the problem is that that same code `window["about"]` in Chrome and IE (7 & 8) returns the actual HTML object.  From the example above, it would return the following:

```
    <div id="about">
     <!-- content here -->
    </div>
```

Why does this happen?

Also, is there a better way to check and see if the `about` object is available, than using the `window` element? I realize ideally one doesn't want to junk up the window object but that is a different question all together.

Thanks

Comment: rather than window['about'], try `about`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebKit browsers seem to ape the old IE behavior of treating element "id" values as properties of the `window` object.

I dislike the behavior, personally.

Comment: +1 [Yes, it's in the HTML5 spec apparently](http://dropshado.ws/post/5142506488/named-access-on-the-window-object). The whole idea of "don't pollute the global namespace" goes up in flames. Because of things like `location` and `document`, it isn't even reliable.

Comment: Dislike would be understating my hatred of this :)

Comment: So if its in the HTML5 spec to suck in this way... How would you recommend I check for the existence of 'about'?

Comment: Well, you can always check for the **value** of "about" being a DOM element as opposed to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will take any ID in the HTML and turn it into a global variable. You can overwrite the assignment, but I assume you're checking for existence and not overwriting perhaps?

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/Hnw7y/

Comment: Right, and it will already exist there because Chrome is taking element ID as `window.example = document.getElementById('example')`

Answer (score 1):

One way to differentiate between the `HTMLElement` and the function would be to check the object's type:

```
if (typeof window.about === 'function') {
    // the 'about' function has been defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way you can do this is the following:

```
function global(name) { return eval(name); }

if( global("about") )
   ...
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/PMqPv/1/