# Javascript Variables Variable (Syntax Error)

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable which contains IDs.

```
var mediaid = '5';
```

And i have a variable set

```
var t1 = 'First';
var t2 = 'Second';
var t3 = 'THird';
etc...
```

I'm trying to get variable's variable inside of jQuery's .append function.

```
$('#block').append('<span>{t+mediaid}</span>');
```

For example if mediaid is 3, `{t+mediaid}` should be t3. But i have syntax errors. Can you fix it..

Comment: @Quentine normally i will use an array but this time there is a detail, so i can't use array. I'm not writing this detail because it's not related with my question :) But thank you you're right :)

Comment: @Eray Although that detail is not related to this question, I would still like to hear about it. Could you please elaborate why you need that variable set (in short)?

Comment: @Sime, this set (t1, t2, t3...) contains long texts and i need to find (for example) 5th element quickly when i need. If i use array (`t['lorem','ipsum','lorem'....]`) i can't find 11th element easily

Comment: @Eray, yes you can.... 11th element = `t[11-1]`

Comment: @Eray You can place each string in its own line. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/CTCra/).

Comment: @Neal, i can do it via javascript ofcourse but i'm not talking about that :) I can't explain it very well. I will need find these elements via looking source code.Never mind my problem is solved with your helps . Thank you Neal and Sime  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#block').append('<span>'+{t+mediaid}+'</span>');
```

I dont think that this is possible.

You might have to do :

```
$('#block').append('<span>'+window['t'+mediaid]+'</span>');
                           //if all those variables are in the window's scope
```

Better:

```
var mediaid = '5';
var t = ['', 'first', 'second', 'third', ...];

$('#block').append('<span>'+t[mediaid]+'</span>');
```

Comment: No, that will return the value of `t` (undefined) and `mediaid` rather than the variable he wants.

Comment: @Jeremy, that is what is there

Comment: @Neal The `null` value usually represents an empty object reference. Since the other values are strings, an empty string (`''`) would be more appropriate I believe...

Comment: @sime, that is true.. changed it

Answer (score 1):

Why not store your variables in an array instead of magically-named variables? Then you can access array elements by index.

```
var mediaid = 5;
var t = [
    'Zeroth',
    'First',
    'Second'
    // etc...
];

$('#block').append('<span>' + t[mediaid] + '</span>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#block').append('<span>' + eval('t'+mediaid) + '</span>');
```

Comment: you is not need of 'eval()' for this, access the variable by 'window ' object
$('#block').append(['<span>' , window[t + mediaid], '</span>'].join(''));

Comment: @The Mask: if your document will contain `<div id=t5></div>` 
then `window["t5"]` will return you reference to that DOM element, not value of variable `t5`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130340/window-object-acting-strange-in-chrome-and-ie